# Jquery if / else statement not consistent

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code to check a decimal number from a dynamically updated div.

```
$('.numberfield').bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function()
{
    var $numbercheck = $(this).text().substring(1);

    if($numbercheck < 5.00) {
        console.log('lower than 5.00 ' + $numbercheck);  
    } 
    else {
        console.log('higher than 5.00 ' + $numbercheck);
    }
});
```

But when i reach a number higher than 5.00 it also triggers the lower if

Also, it seems to be triggering the IF condition no matter what.

```
> lower than 5.00 
> lower than 5.00 0.12
```

(2 lines triggered on each bind change)

```
> lower than 5.00 
> lower than 5.00 1.28

> lower than 5.00 
> higher than 5.00 12.89

> lower than 5.00 
> higher than 5.00 129.00

> lower than 5.00 
> higher than 5.00 129.00
```

So I guess the main problem is, why is the 'lower' always being triggered?

I am using Jquery 1.4.4

EDIT:
I am thinking this may have something to do with the DOM being updated in 2 location simultaneously, thus triggering.

Comment: it's not so a good practice comparing strings with ints and or floats

Comment: A couple questions/comments. 1) `.bind()` is deprecated in favor of `.on`. 2) Why are you using the DOMSubtreeModified event? 3) Your output does not match your code - it should say `5.00` in your output. Was that a typo in your question, or is the real code different than what you've provided?

Comment: The fact that you are getting nothing after `lower than 5` in the initial console log on each change should tell you something. Namely, that the `$numbercheck` value is an empty string. And, since `"" < 5.00 === true`, it always passes. I think you're capturing more event occurrences than you expect. The solution is simple; check `$(this).text()` for length before comparing, or find a different event to capture.

Comment: @ mhodges 1) Stuck with Jquery 1.4.4  2) I am checking the value of a div field so .change doesnt work. 3) yes, typo, fixed.

Comment: @ Mike McCaughan I think you are on to something, I need another event to capture because the DOM is being altered twice simultaneously by another script when the number changes.

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing a `string` to a `float` which is not best practice. First, you must convert your string to a float using `parseFloat` then check if your variable is not `NaN` by using `isNaN(your_float)`. if not, you can proceed to your conditions.

You can use this instead:

```
$('.numberfield').bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function()
{
    //you need to remove all space and comma because unary operator "+" will return NaN if you have spaces or comma
    var $numbercheck = +($(this).text().substring(1).replace(' ', '').replace(',',''));
    if (!isNaN($numbercheck)) { //check if string is parsed
        if($numbercheck < 5.00) {
            console.log('lower than 5.00 ' + $numbercheck);  
        } 
        else if ($numbercheck > 5.00){
            console.log('higher than 5.00 ' + $numbercheck);
        }
        else {
            console.log($numberCheck + ' is equal to 5.00');
        }
    }
    else {
       console.log('error parsing number');
    }
});
```

also, may I suggest you remove `$` from your `numbercheck` variable so as to distinguish it from `JQuery`.

Comment: Change `parseFloat` to `Number` or `+` and this will be the correct solution with input validation. Also, you may want to replace `,` as well, as `Number()` will choke, and `parseInt` or `parseFloat` will only return what is before the commas

Comment: I am still getting the same behaviour with this solution: `> lower than 5.00 0
> higher than 5.00 16.3
> lower than 5.00 0
> higher than 5.00 16.31`

Comment: I think the double trigger as to do with the DOM being updated 2x (by another script) when the .numberfield changes..

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Unary plus (+) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_()) to convert `+$numbercheck` into a number.

And also you can refactor your code:

```
$('.numberfield').bind('DOMSubtreeModified', function () {
  var $numbercheck = $(this).text().substring(1),
      message = +$numbercheck < 5.00 ? 'lower than 5.00 ' : 'higher than 5.00 ';

  console.log(message + $numbercheck);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for using actual `string -> Number` coercion instead of parsing.

Comment: You really do need an `isNaN()` check here, though, because NaN  compared with any value will return false

Comment: youd also need to check for spaces.

Comment: I think `$('.numberfield')` most be a numeric input field and that will prevent the need of extra checks..

Comment: @Yosvel Quintero .numberfield is a div field, not an input field. THis script also returns double :(

Answer (score 1):

$numbercheck is a string as a result of a substring operation and you are comparing it with a float number. As you are comparing strings with numbers it is giving you a result that you are not expecting.

You should use parseFloat($numbercheck) https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parsefloat.asp if you want to compare to a float.

Comment: This doesn't tell the full story. DOM event is firing twice, once with empty value, once with the actual value. Also, parsing over coercion is just asking for bugs.